# Given the premises ∀x.(p(x) ⇒ q(x)) and ∀x.(q(x) ⇒ r(x)), use the Fitch system to prove the conclusion ∀x.(p(x) ⇒ r(x))

Tags: fitch

I'm not able to move forward from step 4. I've tried Implication Introduction applied to 3 and 4 but nothing happens, any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you started in a good way. You can assume p(X) and use Implication Elimination to derive q(X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As F.Zer commented, before you can use Implication Introduction you must first make an assumption.

You must derive `r(X)` *under the assumption of* `p(X)`, so that you may derive `p(X) ⇒ r(X)` by Implication Introduction.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I followed those steps and figured it out. I'm leaving the answer here just in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Final answer for this exercise is in the screenshot below.